# Issue assigning form fields in the HTML template django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a model form and I wanted to know if it is possible to take a model form and assign the name of the specific field when it is running through a for loop within the template html file.

Here is what i have in the current html template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Add members to {{record.name}}</h1>
  {% if message %}
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  {% endif %}
  <form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for trans in transactions %}
      {% if trans.record.id == record.id %}
        {{ trans.user.username }}
        {{ form.as_p }}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <p>Tax: <input type="text" name="tax" value=""></p>
    <p>Tip: <input type="text" name="tip" value=""></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

here is the current form model:

```
class IndividualSplitTransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['amount', 'description']
```

currently the format is looking like this:

```
omar
amount
description
hani
amount
description
assad
amount
description
tax
tip
```

so when i process it and i want to grab the amount assigned to each of the specific users and update a record. I want it to look something like this for easier processing in the view.

```
omar
omaramount
omardescription
hani
haniamount
hanidescription
assad
assadamount
assaddescription
tax
tip
```

so that when i am processing I can properly assign the corrent amount and description for each user when i am updating existing records with the amount.

is it possible to do that within the template itself or would i have to do it somewhere else.

**UPDATED**

So i tried to change my code and update it to get what i am trying to get but this is what i am getting...

Here is the html

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Add members to {{record.name}}</h1>
  {% if message %}
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  {% endif %}
  <form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for trans in transactions %}
      {% if trans.record.id == record.id %}
        {% for field in form %}
          <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ trans.user.username }}{{ field.label }}{{ field|safe }}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <p>Tax: <input type="text" name="tax" value=""></p>
    <p>Tip: <input type="text" name="tip" value=""></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

and here is what I am getting.

[request returs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Uvf.png)

So if you look at the image, it is still just returning the last amount and description of the three that i entered... should i just create the whole form manually in the html file....

Comment: it's not clear what omaramount.  is it the amount in omar account? is it an input field on you just want to display it?

Comment: i want it to display the fillowing types of input fields

omar (not input)
omaramount (this would be decimal field input with cycled username + amount)
omardecription(this would be a charfield input with cycled username + description)

basically a way that when it cycles through each of the users in the record, add the username right before the fields name in the model by creating one string with both combined. When i want to save the values i can do the same where i create a string with username and field name and save the correct informaiton for each user.... does that make sense.

Comment: OK. and what type of fields  it is showing now? and can you share your views.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted the `username + amount` or `username + description`, then you to change away from [form.as_p](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#as-p), because you will get the html `<p><p/>` tag for each field with label preceding it.

You want to dynamically add `username` then do by designing your own html content of the [form manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

There is a [label_suffix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.label_suffix), but prefix is not available. Even with `suffix` you should be doing it at the time of creating the form object.

**Update**:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ trans.user.username }} {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I looked at how to do it manually, but i feel like it is not showing me how to exactly set a custom form field name so that when i call it in the view, it is not all the same name for the field every time i loop thorugh it....

Comment: is it possible to do something like this
{% for field in form %}
    {% if field.amount == 'amount' %}
          {% field.name = tans.user.username + 'amount' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
that is kind of what i want to do within the html file.

Comment: Just now added a snippet, you can loop through the field and add prefix `{{ trans.user.username }}` before the `{{ field.label_tag }}`

Comment: Or before `{{ field.label }}`

Comment: so if I add the username tag before the label_lag followed by the field, when i call amount = cd[' omaramount '], it would return the amount with the username with the amount value entered by the person who submitted the form....

Comment: @OmarJandali I guess for that you need to ensure the `field` should have unique `id`'s for their text box, checkout `{{ field.id_for_label }}` in the documentation.

Comment: should i just create the form manually because i can setup the name exactly how i want it without used the form and going through all of this

Comment: That's basically your data being sent is not correct, check your request in network tab when you submit the form.